# Access to Shared Memory in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

I'm passing 3 arrays, with size `N`=224, to a kernel. The kernel itself calls another function `foo(threadIdx.x)` and foo calls another function `bar(i)` where `i` goes from 1 to 224. The second function needs to access the arrays passed to the kernel, but the code I have now tells me that the argument `i` is undefined.

I tried to save a copy of arrays into a shared memory but it didn't work:

```
__global__ void dummy(double *pos_x_d, double *pos_y_d, double *hist_d){

    int i = threadIdx.x;
    hist_d[i]=pos_x_d[i]+pos_y_d[i];
    __syncthreads();
    
    foo(i);
    __syncthreads();

}
```

The Host code looks like:

```
cudaMalloc((void **) &pos_x_d,(N*sizeof(double)));
cudaMalloc((void **) &pos_y_d,(N*sizeof(double)));
cudaMalloc((void **) &hist_d,(N*sizeof(double)));

//Copy data to GPU
cudaMemcpy((void *)pos_x_d, (void*)pos_x_h,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy((void *)pos_y_d, (void*)pos_y_h,N*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

//Launch Kernel
dummy<<<1,224>>>(pos_x_d,pos_y_d,hist_d);
```

Is it possible to launch two kernels, 1st to send data to shared memory. Then, the second to do the calculations? I also need to loop over the second kernel, which is why I wanted to send data in the shared memory in the first place. The error is coming from line 89, 90 which means it has to do with the shared memory. Complete code is [here](http://pastebin.com/vRiL7Png).

Comment: The lifetime of shared memory is limited to the lifetime of a kernels thread block (AFAIK) p.

Comment: @Dominik Selzer It is not working when I use single thread either. I call a function f1, which calls another function f2. error is coming from my call to f2, which needs to access array passed to the kernel.

Comment: I took a quick look at your code and i only see two separate kernel calls. The first call only fills the shared memory but shared memory is not used afterwards.

Comment: Ok ... i checked again (it's late :-) ). The problem is - as i already told you that shared memories lifetime is per block and per kernel. The second kernel call does not know anything about the shared memory you used in kernel 1. That's not the way you use shared memory. Shared memory is used for non-global inter-thread communication per block.

Comment: @Dominik Selzer That is one of the issue, I think, because I also tried it with single Kernel call and it gave me same errors.

Comment: If the error was the same (undefined symbol) it's because you did not provide the information to access the memory (addresses of the arrays).

Comment: @Dominik Selzer hmmm...that could be the problem. I thought since overlap and metropolis_step were both device functions, they would have access to the array in shared memory. If that's not the case, is there a way to go forward? Both functions overlap, metropolis need that access...Sadly, I can't send array as an argument to these functions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to launch two kernels, 1st to send data to shared memory. Then, the second to do the calculations?

No, it's not possible.  The lifetime of shared memory is the threadblock associated with that shared memory.  A threadblock cannot reliably use the values stored by a different threadblock (whether from the same or different kernel launch) in shared memory.

The only way to save data from one kernel launch to the next is via global memory (or host memory).

Comment: That makes sense. Should using cudaMemcpyToSymbol solve my problem of getting errors like "a host variable "pos_x_h" cannot be directly read in a device function"? I've defined the calling function as __host____device__ for safety at it still doesn't change anything.

Comment: No I don't think that will fix anything.  I took a look at your code, it seems to have a variety of errors in it, but I don't see where that particular issue would arise.

Comment: I think I pinpointed most of my mistakes. I declared my position error by doing __device__ global and it seems to have taken care of everything (fingers crossed). I just edited the code to reflect that. The errors that I'm getting right now are assignment errors. I bet I messed up with pointers again.

Comment: The cudaMemcpy operations after the kernels looked messed up to me.

Comment: yes, I saw that, and I deleted that section after kernel. The errors that I'm getting right now comes from me trying to assign/edit values in global memory (which is a pointer). If this part works, then I think I have a good shot at making this thing work...